# How to handle click event in jquery for a button?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a grid view in which I have a button feild for deleting that particular row in the grid view, using the GridView_RowDeleting() event.

So when that particular row gets renders it's such

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderBodyMasterPage$grdvwUsers','Delete$0')" class="delete" />
```

The delete functionality works fine.

But I want to show a confirmation message on this button click whether to delete the user or not.
For that I have added query code for that to display the confirmation message, but thats not working , don't know why,

```
            $(".delete").click(function(e) {
              // code for displaying the confirmation dialog
            });
```

Please help me out, thanks !

Comment: Do you have to use jQuery for this? Because there is a solution with teh Ajax Control Toolkit?

Comment: it's doing a postback regardless of what jQuery you bind to it, isn't it?

Comment: @hunter- yes you are right, its doing a post back regardless of whatever jquery code is there.

Comment: Thanks everybody, I found out the solution.

Comment: Which is? Post it here for future reference.

Comment: Solution is -                                                          $(".delete").live("click", function(e) {});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the postback is executed prior to the click handler. The following works, but it is ugly ([test code here](http://jsfiddle.net/JTKSy/9/)):

```
$(function () {
    var $button = $(".delete");

    var command = $button.attr('onclick'); // Keep the inline command
    $button.removeAttr('onclick'); // Clear the inline onclick

    $button.click(function() {
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            eval(command.replace('javascript:', '')); // Call the stored command
        }
    });
});
```

I would suggest using the Confirm Button Extender from the Ajax Control Toolkit

Comment: @lalibi- Its still doing a post back and not showing a dialog also, if I use the above code.

Comment: @Bibhu - Try `'javascript:'` instead of `'javascript: '` in the above code. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Haven´t tested it but try it out

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
  return confirm('Are you sure?');
});
```

...it should work ;)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. The inline javascript executes first.

Comment: @lalibi  - what do you mean by "The inline javascript executes first" ?

Comment: @Bibhu - By inline javascript I mean `javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$...','Delete$0')`

Comment: It works for LinkButtons as it used the "href" attribute instead of "onClick". :)

Answer (score 0):

you define one handler in your element:

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderBodyMasterPage$grdvwUsers','Delete$0')" class="delete" />
```

you must put this action in jquery click function

Answer (score 0):

With the API for the latest version of jQuery, it would be something along the line of this:

```
$("#myButton").on('click', function () {
    // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would hook my click event to a jQueryUI dialog popup and then on confirm fire the delete function.

```
$("#ConfirmDialog").dialog({
  title: "Confirm",
  modal: true,
  resizable: false,
  hide: "fade",
  autoOpen: true,
  width 100,
  height: 100,
  buttons:
  {
   "Yes Delete It":function(){
    // Delete function here
    $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    "No, Don't Delete":function() {
    $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }
});
```

what this will do is allow you to have much more control over the popup and make it look like a part of the site vs. a javascript alert box.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the __doPostBack function is executing and preventing your code from executing.  You can use the decoration pattern and wrap the existing __doPostBack to ensure that your code  gets a chance to execute before doing a post back.

[In ASP.NET, how to hook postback event on clientside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290196/in-asp-net-how-to-hook-postback-event-on-clientside)